# Sequelize: Association HasMany only returns one row in nested query

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have these associations:

```js
class PurchaseOrders extends Model{
  static config(sequelize){
        //Configuration
    }
    
    static associate(models){
        this.hasMany(models.OrderItems, {
            as: 'orderItems', 
            foreignKey: 'purchaseOrderId'
        });
    }
}

class OrderItems extends Model{
  static config(sequelize){
        //Configuration
    }
    
    static associate(models){
        this.belongsTo(models.PurchaseOrders, {
            as: 'purchaseOrder',
            sourceKey: 'purchaseOrderId'
        });
    }
}

OrderItems.init(OrderItemsSchema, OrderItems.config(sequelize));
PurchaseOrders.init(PurchaseOrdersSchema, PurchaseOrders.config(sequelize));

OrderItems.associate(sequelize.models);
PurchaseOrders.associate(sequelize.models);
```

And I'm trying to do this nested query:

```js
const rta = await models.PurchaseOrders.findAll({
            include: [
                {
                    model: models.User,
                    as: 'buyer'
                },
                {
                    model: models.OrderItems,
                    as: 'orderItems',
                    required: true
                }
            ]
        });
```

All goes right except that the doesn't return all the order items. Just return the first item and it suppose that is a relation one to many.